# Relation between Galois Cohomology $H^1(\text{Gal(L/K)}, L) = 0$ and $H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K), O_L)=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, homology-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $K$ be a number field and $O_K$be its ring of integers, and $L/K$ be a quadratic extension.

It is known that $H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K), L) = 0$ according to Hilbert's Theorem 90. However, what is known about **$H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K), O_L)$**?

Can this be easily deduced from Hilbert's Theorem 90, or is it essentially unrelated?

**Indivisual solution for $H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K), O_L) = 0$** is also welcomed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150188/discussion-on-question-by-pont-relation-between-galois-cohomology-h1-textgal); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example computation, where $H^i(G,\mathcal O_L)\ne0$. Let $G:=\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-1})/\mathbb Q)=\langle\sigma\rangle$. There is a homomorphism $\mathbb Z[G]\to\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]:1\mapsto1+\sqrt{-1},\sigma\mapsto 1-\sqrt{-1}$, with an exact sequence:
$$0\to\mathbb Z[G]\to\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]\to\mathbb Z/2\to 0.$$
Since $\mathbb Z[G]$ is cohomologically trivial (by Shapiro's lemma), for any $i>0$,
$$H^i(G,\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}])\simeq H^i(G,\mathbb Z/2)\simeq\mathbb Z/2.$$

---

As a trivial remark, since $L\simeq\mathcal O_L\otimes\mathbb Q$, we have:
$$H^i(G,\mathcal O_L)\otimes\mathbb Q\simeq H^i(G,L)=0,$$
i.e., $H^i(G,\mathcal O_L)$ is torsion.

Comment: Thank you very much.It is ver different from the case ground field is local one...

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the local field case?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821791/h1-textgall-k-o-l-0-for-local-fields