# $H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K), O_L)=0$ for local fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology, local-field, galois-cohomology

Let $K$ be a localfield and $O_K$be its ring of integers, and $L/K$ be a quadratic extension.

It is known that $H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K), L) = 0$ according to Hilbert's Theorem 90. However, what is known about **$H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K), O_L)$**?

Can this be easily deduced from Hilbert's Theorem 90, or is it essentially unrelated?

**Indivisual solution for $H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K), O_L) = 0$** is also welcomed. Thank you for your help.

Global case: [Relation between Galois Cohomology $H^1(\text{Gal(L/K)}, L) = 0$ and $H^1(\text{Gal}(L/K), O_L)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821172/relation-between-galois-cohomology-h1-textgall-k-l-0-and-h1-text)

P.S.
**What is the essential difference from Hilbert 90? Similarly to Hilbert 90, if we arbitrarily take a cocycle, doesn't it become a coboundary due to the cocycle condition?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only a partial answer: I just sketch some reasons of the examples I mentioned in the comment of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821172/relation-between-galois-cohomology-h1-textgall-k-l-0-and-h1-text).

See, for example Faltings' paper [Faltings' paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/AST_2002__279__185_0.pdf). Particularly section 2c. Galois cohomology. or Section 3 of [Olsson's article](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emolsson/Olsson2.pdf)

We have ethe following fact:

Let $G$ be a finite group, $A$ is a commutative ring (with unit), $B$ an $A$-algebra with $G$-action and $A\to B$ is a almost etale covering (see section 2 of [Faltings' paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/AST_2002__279__185_0.pdf) for definition). Let $M$ be a $B$-module with semilinear $G$-action.
Then $H^p(G,M)$ is almost zero (see section 1 of [Faltings' paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/AST_2002__279__185_0.pdf) for definition): the idea is that the cohomology group is killed by elements in $A$ of the form $Tr(B):=\{a=\sum_{g\in G}g(b), b\in B\}$, and the "almost etale covering" implies that the image of trace is very big. (killed by something "big" means it was very "small".)

Take $A\to B$ as $O_K\to O_L$ in your case: then if $L/K$ is somehow "almost etale" will imply $Tr(O_L)$ contain all positive valuation elements of $O_K$, including $p$.) (Sees for example [a lecture note](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/252Page/handouts/almostetale.pdf) for some details of this phenomenon.) Hence in particular $H^i(Gal(L/K), O_L)$ will be almost zero, and invert $p$ it tells  $H^i(Gal(L/K), L)=0$.

---

Last few words about those examples I mentioned related with perfectoid fields.
Denote $C=\widehat{\overline{\mathbf{Q}_p}}$, we consider for example $K=\mathbf{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^{\infty}})$, then the observation is that (see corollary 185 [another lecture notes](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/notes.pdf)) the trace image $Tr(O_L)$ for any finite extension $L/K$ is big (contains $\mathfrak{m}_L$) and hence $H^i(Gal(L/K), O_L)$ will be almost zero. (as you can see, from the same lecture note theorem 183, this should be a corollary of the "Almost purity for perfectoid fields", in other words some how from the fact as I phrased "$\widehat{K}$ is a perfectoid field in $C$".)

What is left is then some details and somehow "passing to the limit", for example use the observation $H^i(G_K, O_{\overline{K}} /p^mO_{\overline{K}}) = \varinjlim_{L} H^i(Gal(L/K), O_{L}/p^m O_{L})$ to finally conclude what I said $H^1(G_K, O_C)$ is almost zero.

(Notice also that in the concrete examples I gave, $C$ is not a "local field" (its valuation is not discrete), though we are in the $p$-adic world.)

Comment: What is the essential difference from Hilbert 90? Similarly to Hilbert 90, if we arbitrarily take a cocycle, doesn't it become a coboundary due to the cocycle condition?

Comment: I think this easily follows from Hilbert theorem 90 .Am I mistaken?

Comment: Generally, there are differences between group cohomology and (continuous) Galois cohomology. For the latter, to apply Hilbert 90, we can only endow $G$-module with discrete topology [see case(2) Example A.104](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/~fontaine/galoisrep.pdf)). If we only consider group coho, then Hilbert 90 tells $H^1(Gal(L/K), L^{\ast})=\{1\}$; a related result: $H^i(Gal(L/K), GL_n(L))=0$ for any $i>0$ and $n\geq1$ ($n=1$ is our case). But it does not discuss $H^i(Gal(L/K), O_L)$ in general and  not even something like "almost $0$" (it doesn't even make sense generally)

Comment: conti last comm, for gp coho (not Gal coho), yes $H^1(G_K, C)=0$ seems also follows from Hil90 and the observation $G_K\simeq Aut_{\widehat{K}}(C)$ ([a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4794371/absolute-galois-group-of-the-p-adic-completion-of-a-valuation-field)). The fact $H^i(G_K, GL_n(O_C))\sim 0$  is a particular case, but at least discussed valuation ring and "almost 0" is nice. Surely there can be other partial results, but in general I don't know what one can say except (apply $(-)^{Gal(L/K)}$) the long exact sequence drawn form $0\to O_L\to L\to L/O_L\to 0$ (as modules).